# Added unexpected lines of codes in yarn.lock file

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, yarn-lock.json, yarnrc

I pulled React js repository from git. and ran `yarn install` then added 6k+ lines of codes in `yarn.lock` file I expected 4k or less. Is it any version issue? or is it a yarn issue?

**node version: v18.7.0**

**yarn version: 3.4.1**

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

My yarn version was 3.4.1. I downgraded to 1.22.19 using `yarn set version 1.22.19`